# Override default model webapi output magento2

Tags: magento2, overrides, rest-api, webapi

I've began creating a module for a rest api for creditmemos - which I intend on using as an alternative to the built in version.

At the moment I've started the normal way for creating a webapi module, by creating a `webapi.xml` which links to an interface. I've taken a slight tangent by creating a `preference` tag in my `di.xml` like so;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <preference for="Vendor\Module\Api\MemoInterface" type="\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\CreditmemoRepository"/>
</config>
```

This actually has worked.

I need to know how I can get more control over the data that is output than the default api. At the moment there is a large mass of data which is output and I'm unsure how to limit and curate this data.